# Polynomial Equation Problem with Complex Roots

Tags: complex-numbers, quadratics, radicals, substitution, cubics

How could one find the complex or imaginary roots of any equations like

$$x+\sqrt[3]{x}-2=0$$

One of its roots is $1$, but what is/are the other/s?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $\sqrt[3]{x}=t$.

Hence, we have: $$t^3+t-2=0$$ or:
$$t^3-t^2+t^2-t+2t-2=0$$ or:
$$(t-1)(t^2+t+2)=0,$$ which gives:
$$\sqrt[3]{x}=-\frac{1}{2}\pm\frac{\sqrt7}{2}i$$ or: $x=1$.

Comment: So it means that this quadratic equation will have three roots?

Comment: So it has three roots

Comment: I think it's not quadratic equation.

Comment: Then what is it sir?

Comment: After substitution $t=\sqrt[3]x$ it's a cubic equation.

Comment: Sir,How did you find the roots of $t^2+t+2=0$

Comment: $t^2+t+2=t^2+t+\frac{1}{4}+\frac{7}{4}=\left(t+\frac{1}{2}\right)^2-\left(\frac{\sqrt7}{2}i\right)^2=\left(t+\frac{1}{2}+\frac{\sqrt7}{2}i\right)\left(t+\frac{1}{2}-\frac{\sqrt7}{2}i\right)$

Comment: You are welcome!

Answer (score 13):

One can make the substitution $t^3=x$ so that the equation becomes a cubic in $t$:
$$t^3+t-2=0$$
As you say, $x=1\iff t=1$ is a solution, so we can divide the polynomial in $t$ by $t-1$ to obtain a quadratic (I leave the long division or factoring to you). Then the resulting quadratic can be solved by the quadratic formula (or factoring if its easy enough).

> So you can check your long division: the resulting quadratic should be $$t^2+t+2$$, and this has negative discriminant so it has complex roots.

Then you just use $x=t^3$ to obtain the solutions in $x$.

Comment: I like the answer format of including a spoiler!

Comment: Ah yes, of course. Thanks @PaulSinclair

Answer (score 1):

write $$\sqrt[3]{x}=2-x$$ and raise to the power three
your equation is equivalent to $$-(x-1) \left(x^2-5 x+8\right)=0$$